# HTTP DELETE and PUT methods are showing during http OPTIONS method request even after disabling

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat9, http-delete, http-put

I am trying to disable http PUT and DELETE method in webapplication hosted on Apache Tomcat 9 server. Even though web application doesn't accept PUT and DELETE method but whenever I hit the url with OPTIONS method it does show PUT and DELETE method in allowed methods. Things that I have tried to fix it but didn't work so far

1. Adding security constraint in Tomcat/conf/web.xml file as below
   [image]
2. Adding security constraint, same as above,in web.xml located inside the app/WEB-INF/web.xml file
3. I found out that if I hit just tomcat admin url with OPTIONS method it shows only   GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS as allowed method but when I am appending app uri in it the allowed methods are GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH

The APP url response
[image]

The server url response

[image]